# use static block to add banner underneath nav bar but only on category pages

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, catalog, xml, static-block

I want to add a banner directly underneath the nav bar but I only want it to display on category pages, I have added a static block in cms and I have had it display on all pages via using the header.phtml file (and just putting it at the end of the file) but I only want to to display on category pages so I can't use the header.phtml file as that is called on all pages and there is no category template that I can call it in that will display it where I want it. I have tried adding:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="top_images">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>top_images</block_id></action> </block>
```

into catalog.xml (in the layout folder of my theme) but that doesn't seem to show up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this add this your header it will show block only on category pages

```
<?php  $currentUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true));
if (strpos($currentUrl,'catalog/category') == true) { echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('top_images')->toHtml(); } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just worth mentioning that I originally got a PHP error with this code but ofc you just missed a semi-colon, always that way!

Comment: <?php  $currentUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true));
if (strpos($currentUrl,'catalog/category') == true) { echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('top_images')->toHtml(); } ?>